# Cannot change QAction's icon

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to toggle QAction's icon. It depends on context of a specific table. Actually, it's working whenever I start message.cpp, but it wouldn't change when I'm on message.cpp. I expect `updateIcon()` will change my icon if I click on m_action4, but it doesn't. Could I repaint QAction?

Firstly, I set variable on header:

**message.h:**

```
private:
QAction *m_action4;
```

*Here is my code on source:*
**message.cpp:**

```
    QSqlQuery query0;
    m_action4 = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/silent1.png"), tr("Mute"), this);
    m_muteActive = false;
    query0.prepare("SELECT state FROM mute_state WHERE p_id=?");
    query0.addBindValue(m_pid);
    query0.exec();
    if (query0.next() && query0.value(0) == "1" )
    {
        {
            m_muteActive = true;
            m_action4->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/speaker.png"));
        }
    }
    m_actionBar->addButton(m_action4);
    connect(m_action4, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(muteMessages()));

muteMessages()
{    
      QSqlQuery query; 
      query.prepare("UPDATE mute_state SET state=? , duration= ? , type=? WHERE p_id=?");
      if (m_muteActive)
      {
          query.addBindValue("0");
          query.addBindValue("0");
          m_muteActive = false;
      }
      else
      {
          query.addBindValue("1");
          query.addBindValue("525949");
          m_muteActive = true;
      }
      query.addBindValue("private");
      query.addBindValue(m_id);
      if (query.exec())
          qDebug()<<"query was executed";
    }
  QTimer::singleShot(100 , this, SLOT(updateIcon()));
}
updateIcon()
{
    if (m_muteActive)
        m_action4->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/silent1.png"));    
    else    
        m_action4->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/speaker.png"));    
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to call `updateIcon` from a slot. You can invoke it directly. And, as it stands, the code you've posted works fine.

Comment: As the painting of a QAction depends on the context the action is used in, you should add information on your platform and where you’re observing the action failing to update its icon, e.g. toolbar, menu, etc. Also, what do you mean by "Actually, it's working whenever I start message.cpp, but it wouldn't change when I'm on message.cpp”? "Starting" a cpp file or "being on it” doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: it's kind of toolbar. and when I close this dialog and restart it , it's working. but it's not updated icon on that moment which I click on it.@FrankOsterfeld

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted works fine. Here it is, after removing the SQL queries that are not necessary to demonstrate it:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QAction>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPainter>

class Ui : public QWidget {
   QGridLayout m_grid;
   QToolBar m_actionBar;
   QIcon m_silent, m_speaker;
   QAction m_action4;
   bool m_muteActive;
   QPixmap drawText(const char * text, int size = 64) {
      QPixmap pix(size, size);
      QPainter p(&pix);
      p.setFont(QFont("helvetica", size*0.8));
      p.fillRect(pix.rect(), Qt::white);
      p.drawText(pix.rect(), QString::fromUtf8(text));
      return pix;
   }
public:
   Ui() :
      m_grid(this),
      m_silent(drawText("")),
      m_speaker(drawText("")),
      m_action4(tr("Mute"), this),
      m_muteActive(false)
   {
      m_grid.addWidget(&m_actionBar, 0, 0);
      m_actionBar.addAction(&m_action4);
      connect(&m_action4, &QAction::triggered, this, &Ui::muteMessages);
      updateIcon();
   }
   Q_SLOT void muteMessages() {
      m_muteActive = !m_muteActive;
      updateIcon();
   }
   Q_SLOT void updateIcon() {
      m_action4.setIcon(m_muteActive ? m_silent : m_speaker);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   Ui ui;
   ui.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```